# IP address of virtual Linux

Tags: virtual-machine, ip

I have a native Linux. I also have a virtual Linux on it. I can ping anything from the virtual Linux but I cannot ping virtual Linux from outside. The virtual Linux has static IP address. The host has dynamic IP address I searched and I found I should config /etc/networks/interface. Is it the right place to solve this problem? Or what can be the problem? Thanks, David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be using NAT as the default network behavior. In this mode you cannot access the virtual machine from outside, and this includes the host machine (as that is "outside" as well).

Change your network card to "Bridged", and try again.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Before your answer I tried out many ideas. There is one thing that I cannot make to be back up. When I remove a line from routing table like this: sudo route del -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 metric 0 I should do it every time when I reboot system. How can I do it to be permament?

Comment: With this line I cannot ping anything.

Comment: I am sorry I checked and it works.
Everything works perfectly. :-)